# Change default locale behavior for currency formatting

Tags: ios, concurrency, nsnumberformatter

I am facing a strange problem. My app relies on a double conversion:

> currency string -> number -> currency string

Basically, the single conversions are realized through the built-in localization functions of iOS. I recently found that the app does not work properly when the user uses CHF as currency. Apparently the default for this locale is to round all currency values to the nearest 5 cents. (eg. CHF 1.28 will become CHF 1.30, and 1.21 CHF will become CHF 1.20).

For a bunch of reasons it's easier for me to solve the formatting convention than solve the bug for that only locale.

Do you know a way to force the conversion to use a more detailed rounding approach (eg. 0.01 instead of 0.05) for every locale?

Thank you!

Comment: Since there are no answers, I have to accept mine ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an interesting solution:

```
currencyFormatter  = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:YES];
[currencyFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
// This will force the rounding behavior:
[currencyFormatter setRoundingIncrement:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.01]];
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Have noticed that if you set currency code after you set the rounding increment the set rounding increment is reset in accordance with the set currency.